# Two nav classes for responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, nav, semantic-markup

I've been studying the basics of web design for a month now and I've been trying to create a semantically correct responsive header for a fictional website. The code I wrote today creates the look I'm aiming for, but the problem is that I'm not sure if the code's actually good and if I'm on the right path.

```js
// Sidenav Toggle //
function togNav() {
  "use strict";
  var side = document.getElementById("sidenav"),
    main = document.getElementById("container");

  if (side.style.transform === "translateX(0%)") {
    side.style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
    main.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
  } else {
    side.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
    main.style.transform = "translateX(40%)";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Side Navigation */

#sidenav {
  /* Styling */
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  /* Positioning */
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  /* UX */
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

#sidenav a {
  padding: 3rem;
  display: block;
}

#sidenav a:hover {
  color: #8cc63e;
  transition: 0s;
}


/* /////////////////////////////////////////////////// */
/* ////////////////////// HEADER ///////////////////// */
/* /////////////////////////////////////////////////// */


/* Header - Container */

header {
  /* Styling */
  height: 50rem;
  background: lightblue;
}


/* Header - Small Navigation */

header>nav.small {
  /* Styling */
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

header>nav.small>.wrapper {
  /* Styling */
  height: 8rem;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  /* Flexbox */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header>nav.small #burger {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

header>nav.small #burger .bar {
  /* Style */
  width: 2.25rem;
  height: 0.3rem;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 0.4rem;
}


/* Header - Large Navigation */

header>nav.large {
  /* Styling */
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

header>nav.large>.wrapper {
  /* Styling */
  height: 8rem;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  max-width: 96rem;
  /* Flexbox */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header>nav.large ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

header>nav.large ul li a {
  padding-left: 4.5rem;
}

header>nav.large ul li a:hover {
  color: #8cc63e;
}


/* Header - Media Queries */

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  header>nav.small {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  header>nav.large {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* General Styling */

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body,
a {
  margin: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  text-decoration: none;
}

#container {
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<!-- Off Canvas -->
<div id="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
</div>

<!-- On Canvas -->
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <nav class="small">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="burger" onclick="togNav()">
          <div class="bar bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar bar3"></div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="logo">
                        Logo
                    </a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <nav class="large">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="logo">
                        Logo
                    </a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

[View on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Nyenosso/pen/RQyNoe)

As you can see, I used two nav classes in order to create an inline navigation bar for larger screens and a top bar with an off canvas side navigation for smaller screens. I use Flexbox to align the items and Javascript to display the side navigation.

**Question**
My question is: is it semantically correct to use two navigation classes for one introductory header class? Or is there, which I'm guessing there is, a better way to get the result that I'm trying to get with less code? It feels so wrong.

Hopefully my question isn't too vague. Google and other questions on StackOverflow aren't really helping me finding a solution, so I hope you guys can. Also, if you see anything strange or bad with the rest of my code, please tell me! I'm very new to this and I really want to get better at it.

Comment: Although this question might be a little opinion-based for SO, I'd say your code looks pretty functional. I have two minor suggestions: 1) It might be an improvement not to duplicate the navigation HTML. Instead, rely on styles in media queries to turn the desktop nav element into a mobile sidebar. 2) Definitely not mandatory, but I like using a hidden checkbox and adjacent sibling selector to control the sidebar toggle with CSS. Just tickles me not to have to rely on JavaScript. I'll try to work up an example when time permits.

Comment: Wouldn't a navigation like that still require two classes with links? I just looked it up and from what I could find there's not really anything that has an inline navigation that turns into a sidebar with a hidden checkbox... thank you anyways for the help (and for correctly implementing the codepen into my question, really couldn't figure out how to do it)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your menu might feel wrong, but it's quite alright by regular coding standards
2. Your question might feel right, but it encourages opinionated answers and is therefore wrong (off-topic).
3. (opinionated and debatable - the actual answer to your question): ***"I'd say it's not"***. I would personally put in the necessary effort to have only one menu for both cases and style it differently using `@media` queries. But that's more a matter of preference and self-imposed standards than a matter of clear right or wrong (I'd do it because I can, because I like a decent challenge and in the name of DRY principle; arguments that your solution is easier to adapt/adjust to various future change requests and probably easier to understand by other developers are quite valid - in the end, this is a technicality and it takes up development time that is not justified by the minor increase in application performance or code maintainability).

Unrelated to semantic-markup (which seems to be the main topic of your question) and *because you have asked for* any *advice about* your *code*: the one thing I ***really*** disagree with in your code is the `40%` width rule for sidebar. On narrow devices, it makes no sense from usability point of view. With menu opened on narrow devices, you don't want to be able to read the page contents and it makes no sense to cripple the menu to a narrow stripe. Give it a reasonable width (at least `250px` and at most `100vw`).

```js
function togNav() {
  document.querySelector("header").classList.toggle('opened');
}
```

```css
#burger {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% + 12px);
  top: 32px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: left 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px;
}

#burger>div {
  width: 45px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #000;
}

header {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  height: 8rem;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu li {
  display: block;
  border: 0 solid #eee;
  border-right-width: 1px;
}

#menu li:last-child {
  border-right-width: 0;
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu a:hover {
  color: #8cc63e;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

nav {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  nav {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    max-width: calc(100vw - 100px);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), box-shadow 0.3s linear;
  }
  .logo {
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  }
  .opened .logo {
    transform: translateX(65vw);
  }
  header {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: box-shadow .3s linear;
  }
  header.opened {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  header.opened nav {
    transform: translateX(0);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  }
  #menu {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href class="logo">Logo</a>
  <nav>
    <div id="burger" onclick="togNav()">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href>Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href>Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href>Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href>Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

What you should note:

- simpler markup
- simpler JavaScript

If you need the SCSS, it's [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/ge1yomwe/).